# Jquery script event handler not working when appended

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following jquery script that I want to work

```
<?php
$script=<<<SCRIPT
$("#btn").click(function(){
   alert("hello");
});
SCRIPT;

$html=<<<HTML
<input type="button" id="btn" value="clickme">
HTML;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.globalEval('$("#divhoho").prepend("<?php echo $script; ?><script><?php echo $html; ?></script>");');
</script>

<div id='divhoho'></div>
```

The problem is the event handler that I prepend on the div does not work on the html I prepended also

I also tried the jquery live()

```
<?php
    $script=<<<SCRIPT
    $("#btn").live({
            click: function(){
                alert("hello");
            }
            });
    SCRIPT;

   $html=<<<HTML
          <input type="button" id="btn" value="clickme">
    HTML;
?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $.globalEval('$("#divhoho").prepend("<?php echo $script; ?><script><?php echo $html; ?></script>");');
       </script>


        <div id='divhoho'></div>
```

and still it does not work... is this algorithm possible to work? thanks
P.S. The values in the php heredocs are already cleared in newlines so it will not produce any javascript errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("#btn").live('click' ,function(){
                alert('hello');
            }
);
```

Comment: Yes it should work,any way why are you doing like that. Did you check your HTML generated ? Is it align with what you expected?

Comment: sorry... I forgot the prepend() in which the dynamic html and script will be put will be eval using jquery.globalEval(); I already made a correction on the code... maybe the eval is problem but I really need to use eval